# Polishing an user interface

Tags: iphone, android, user-interface

Looking for examples of some "final touches" to enhance an existing (raw) user interface.

I.e nothing related to the core functionalities of the application, but rather examples of all these little details which give an application a "polished" look (new fonts, change in layout, more descriptive labels...others ?)

The target platform will be a mobile platform (android/iphone).

Note that I'm severly graphically impaired regarding colour and shape combinations, so anything too sophisticated will probably pass me by completely ;)

Comment: What language do you use? Is it a web application or winform or what?

Comment: What kind of UI is it can you please be more specific?

Comment: @hgulyan and anijhaw - that would be for a mobile application (iphone and android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check links below

**Android**

http://phandroid.com/2010/05/13/android-developers-blog-ui-best-practices/

http://www.androidjunkies.com/index.php/2010/05/13/android-developers-blog-ui-best-practices/

**iPhone**

Here's a book on this subject

http://apress.com/book/view/1430223596

*articles*

http://iphonedevelopmentbits.com/best-practices-for-developing-an-iphone-ipod-touch-application

http://surgeworksmobile.com/iphone/how-to-build-an-iphone-user-interface-prototype-that-follows-apple-guidelines

I'd recommend you to watch some popular application's design.

Answer (score 5):

With respect to Android, there was a really good blog post that dove into the UI design behind Twitter's official Android app and broke it down into patterns and best practices:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html